# OSD desktop-clock that does not get in your way?

Tags: customization, notification

is there a clock application,

- that can be placed on your screen like a widget
- staying **always on top**
- but automatically **fades away on mouseover**
- enabling you to click through it on items below,

(behaves pretty much **like** the **Ubuntu notifications** in that sense).

I am aware, that there are screenlets and gdesklets widget apps, but those are buggy, look outdated, and do not comply with the criteria listed above.

What I have in mind is a clock that is large, (digital), always visible (on top of all other windows), and does not disrupt your work (e.g. you can still click that scroll bar or button if it is just below the clock, since the clock fades away on hovering).

A tool called "OSD-Lyrics" that show lyrics for songs and behaves exactly the way I described above.

So it should be possible (and even easier) to do the same with a clock.

Comment: Just wondering: what is your objection to the default clock in the top right?

Comment: I want to autohide or completely remove my panel, so the clock would not be always visible, while I'm working. Apart from that, I'd like to have a larger clock with exactly the behaviour, that I described :-)

Comment: I have edited the title and text a little to make my point more clear.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the top panel in the first place ?

Comment: Was I right to assume you're using Ubuntu 10.10 ?

Answer (score 10):

Seems there aren't currently any application fulfilling all your expectations. Hope you got a watch for Christmas ;-) Here are the actual possibilities I see :

- **Screenlet option** : with compiz and the widget layer you can make widgets nicely fade with the `F9` key. Of course it doesn't fade on mouseover and as for the outdated look it's subjective but I think you won't be happy with that solution.
  Personally, I do not autohide my top panel because I want to have time, cpu and ram usage displayed and in that case I would have to press a key.
- **Hacking NotifyOSD** : as you pointed out, the NotifyOSD does almost all you want.
  I made a small Python script implementing this idea : https://gist.github.com/760615.
  Download it and launch `python NotifyOSD_clock.py` in a terminal.
  [image: OSD clock]
  That clock nicely fades away on mouseover of course.
  [image: OSD clock on mouseover]
  However I recommend not using this script as is :

  - it will flood your `$HOME/.cache/notify-osd.log` file
  - it will block other low priority system notifications
  - and you can't move the clock

  If you like that user interface, you would have to reuse the [notify-osd source code](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/notify-osd) to make a standalone application (not so easy for the usual Ubuntu end-user, he !).
- **DIY (almost) from scratch** : SO [recommands libXosd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429648/how-to-do-pretty-osd-in-python) if you want to write your own script.
- **Propose your idea for a future Ubuntu release** : http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/
- **Saving vertical space without getting rid of the top panel** : just by [moving the window buttons in the top panel](http://myinterestingubuntu.blogspot.com/2010/05/saving-vertical-space-with-ubuntu-lucid.html) (cf. point 4) because it allows you to keep the usual clock applet visible.

Personally I wouldn't be happy with that kind of big transparent clock being always over my windows. I'm neither satisfied with the autohide option which hide everything and the top panel already uses too much vertical space. Maybe should we have a mix of autohide and autofadeaway in that panel.

Anyway, having all those vertically-stacked panels, toolbars and tabs isn't the most clever way to fully use our ever-wider screens (nope, I don't spend all my time watching 16:9 movies). I am pleased to see that we might get some improvements with the future [Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/) interface in Ubuntu 11.04 :-)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and your proposals! I will have a more intense look at them in a few days. Heavy work these days. Happy new year! YSN

Comment: Actually this answer is not fully satifactory, but Maxime has stll earned the bounty in my opinion. Now I a transparent AWN-Dock with a clock applet, that almost does what I want.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this bash line just to try, but it doesn't behave in the right way and has the disadvantage to clog the notification system queue.
It's a start, perhaps?

```
while true; do notify-send `date +%H:%M` -t 60000; sleep 60; done;
```

you need to install notify-send

Comment: Thanks for that answer, it could be a starting point at least. I have started a bounty an hope for a good solution, since I cannot work on it myself at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! it's not the most elegant but it's

- lightweight
- configurable
- in the repos!

search synaptic for osd_clock

:)

Comment: For me (14.04) the package is called "osdclock" (a search for "osd_clock" returns nothing) but the command you run once installed is "osd_clock", confusing eh?

Answer (score 0):

osd_clock is fine, I used it as a little date & time printout in the upper right corner.

```
osd_clock -s 0 -o -13 -c white -tr -f -misc-fixed-bold-r-semicondensed--*-*-*-*-c-*-*-* -F '%u  %y%m%d  %R
```

However, osd_clock it seems to work no more in Lubuntu 18.04 "Bionic": the command runs without errors, but no output can be seen. Can anybody confirm this trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Install `osd_bin` and run:

```bash
while true; do date +%I:%M | osd_cat -d 60 -l 2 -A right -p bottom -f "lucidasanstypewriter-bold-12"; sleep 60;done
```

and look at right-down corner of the screen.